# What does SKU stand for in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure

I am requesting a quota increase from Microsoft Azure and have an option of choosing an SKU family from A series to NV series. What does it mean?

Comment: Note for reviewers - This recently came up for a vote for reopening, but in my understanding it's still off-topic since it is about Azure.  Azure is not *"computer software"* or *"computer hardware"* (see [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) guidance), but *Cloud Computing* (hardware/software).  This typically means (again, IMHO) that Azure questions are more suitable for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/azure), but not here on Super User.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I'm happy to migrate the question to Server Fault.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions can't be migrated after 60 days.  It's fine to leave it closed here -- It just doesn't need to be reopened.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Sorry, I used "migrate" in the wrong sense. I meant that I'm happy to delete it here and post the question and answer there, since I wrote both.

Comment: Ah, I got it now.  But no, deleting and reposting probably isn't recommended either.  It has 55k views and 20+ upvotes, so it's been *helpful* to people, even if was off-topic.  It's  a weird nuance of Stack Exchange that off-topic questions can be (a) closed, (b) helpful, (c) get search indexed, (d) get upvoted ... but (e) get no new answers if the information changes.  Not ideal, but the way things work -- And it's not likely that anyone is going to "redefine" SKU anytime soon, so it's probably safe to leave it as-is. :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It stands for "Stock-Keeping Unit. Excerpt from [the Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/product-resources#sku):

> ## Sku
>
> Represents a purchasable Stock Keeping Unit (SKU) under a product. These represent the different shapes of the product.

It seems in line with the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit):

> In the field of inventory management, a stock keeping unit is a distinct type of item for sale.

Comment: From your question it wasn't very clear whether you were asking what "SKU" meant or what a specific prefix in a Microsoft SKU meant but since you were asking the former it feels like this is off-topic as it's a very generic concept used by many retailers.

Comment: Fair point. I found SKU for the first time in a form to raise a ticket with Microsoft, so I assumed it was a technical term and that other users might assume the same. I was surprised that it was a retail term. I'm happy to move the question to another forum or to delete it.