# Azure validation error with NVIDIA GPU Cloud Image

Tags: gpu, azure, cloud

In the process of creating a Virtual Machine with NVIDIA GPU Cloud Image, with
size `Standard NC6s_v3, 6 vcpus, 112 GB memory`, I got a validation error:

> Validation failed. Click here to view details.
>
> Operation results in exceeding quota limits of Core. Maximum allowed: 0, Current in use: 0, Additional requested: 6. Please read more about quota increase at https://aka.ms/ProdportalCRP/?#create/Microsoft.Support/Parameters/{"subId":"...","pesId":"...","supportTopicId":"..."}. (Code: QuotaExceeded)

I still have a lot of credits on Azure. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the quota for the NCv3-series having [a default of zero](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-gpu#ncv3-series):

> For this size family, the vCPU (core) quota in your subscription is initially
>   set to 0 in each region. [Request a vCPU quota increase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request) for this family in an
>   [available region](https://azure.microsoft.com/regions/services/).

If your quota is zero because you are on a free subscription such as an academic sponsorship, Microsoft will probably keep the quota at zero to save these high-demand machines for paying customers.

One quick solution is to use `NV6` instead of `NC6_v3`. The NV-series uses [Tesla M60](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-gpu#nv-series), which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Tesla#Specifications_and_configurations) lists as several generations old compared to the latest V100, but has no quota limitations. After choosing the cloud image on Azure, click "Change size", and change to `NV6`.

If you want to request an increase in quota, first confirm that the NCv3-series is available for your region, e.g. for Europe and UK go [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/global-infrastructure/services/?products=virtual-machines&regions=europe-north,europe-west,united-kingdom-south,united-kingdom-west).

Then, request a quota increase following [the official Microsoft directions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request), or the directions below, which are quicker and more up-to-date:

1. Follow the link in the error message (starting with https://aka.ms), or go to portal.azure.com, click on "Help + support" in the left blade, then
     on "New support request" in the blade second from the left
2. Answer the details in "1. Basics":

   - Issue Type: "Service and subscription limits (quotas)"
   - Subscription: if you can choose, select the subscription ID in the
       error above.
   - Quota type: "Compute/VM (cores/vCPUs) subscription limit
       increases"
   - support plan: you should have "Azure Support Plan - Developer"
       selected
   - click "Next"
3. Answer the details in "2. Problem":

   - Severity: keep the default "C - Minimal impact"
   - Quota details:
   - Deployment model: keep the default "Resource manager"
   - Location: choose a region that has NCv3-series
   - SKU family (see meaning [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1392227/what-does-sku-stand-for-in-microsoft-azure/1392228#1392228)): choose NCSv3. In the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-gpu#ncv3-series), Standard NC6s_v3 is listed under "NCv3" series, which is not listed as an SKU family. The NC family has a default quota of 48 and the NCSv3 has a quota of zero, so I assume that NCSv3 is the right SKU family. (I raised a ticket with Microsoft asking to either change the form drop-down or the documentation.)
   - New limit: "6"
   - click "Save and continue"
4. Click on "Next", enter your contact details, then create the request.

Then you need to wait for Microsoft to increase your quota.